Gnome / OpenBox not working as display manager but lxqt / Lubuntu is
I need Gnome as my display manager. So this is a strange case.
I used to be a windows user but then I switched to Ubuntu and was using Gnome as usual. Everything was fine but one day I installed an app called Texts.com. It was an appImage and It run well the first time but then suddenly my system crashed.
I thought it was a normal error. So when I restarted, it went on the usual screen asking my username and then my password. As soon as I entered the password, the screen crashed and I was shown the following screen.

After this I tried to switch to Openbox and got a plain black screen. Then after much struggle, I got to open the terminal at the login screen, entered the password and installed lxqt / Lubuntu using terminal only, and much to my surprise, the Lubuntu is working fine.
Now I get 4 options in my display manager - openbox (not working) , lxqt desktop (working), GNOME Classic (not working) , Lubuntu (working)
But I don't want to use Lubuntu, and want to go back to GNOME or the normal Ubuntu I used to have.

My recommendation: reinstall Ubuntu and try again. Avoid the temptation to try different window managers or desktop environments. If the problem reoccurs, come back for support. My guess is that it won’t. If it does, I’m sure it will be a much simpler problem to solve than unraveling your rather complicated setup.

GNOME is a desktop and not a display manager, the GNOME DM is actually gdm3.  Lubuntu uses the LXQt desktop, sddm as the DM and openbox as the WM.  I login to an openbox session may not give anything but a black screen; that's expected UNLESS you've setup something to give you background, menus etc (openbox can use obmenu as the obmenu if setup correctly).  Don't forget openbox is only a window manager (WM) & not a full featured UI, unless you configure it as such by adding features/functions (eg. Lubuntu/LXQt uses pcmanfmq-qt to display a background on the system)

You are mixing up ideas/concepts and what applications actually do, thus you problem is probably your expectations are likely incorrect. A openbox session for example by default is simple (black screen with nothing but pointer - ie. it's a minimalist environment and extremely lean; it can't handle even a wallpaper/background by default). Openbox is after all a window manager; it handles the borders around windows, positions etc... and doesn't handle desktop/displays as those are handled by other apps.

To go back to what you had, I'd explore what changes you have actually made, and plan a route that will reverse those changes. If you're like me & use terminal, your bash history (history) should remind you what changes you made (ie. I'd expect to see what files/configs I edited there, what backups of pre-changed-files I made etc), for package changes you can also look at apt logs (/var/log/apt/history.log); ie. it'll show what you installed/removed etc.  I don't know what you did, and your description is confusing, so I'm not sure what to advise. I expect you made mistakes in approach

If you right-click on the black background of an Openbox session, do you see the OBMENU, which is rather limited & basic (but can be expanded, but you have to do that yourself; as openbox by design is a very lean (ie. limited) environment so as to remain 'light')...   If you do, then openbox is working correctly too (though it could be working & you just don't have obmenu installed/setup to run; as I don't know what exactly you did)

FYI: I booted up a pretty clean (ie. unchanged) Lubuntu [23.10] system and logged in with a openbox session. The end result is two black screens and a pointer, ie. an openbox session. On this ~default setup, I do get a OBMENU on right-click of the black background, that gives me Shortcuts/FM/Term/Inter/Apps/Acce/Int/Off/Mult/Sys/Sys/Logout options.  I'd try your system and I suspect you'll get the same. ie. openbox is doing what it's supposed to. Being a window manager, it handles the windows, giving them borders, buttons, allowing resize or movement etc.  Openbox can be used with many DEs

If you try to replace mutter windowmanager with openbox in gnome-session it is not possible anymore. At least I didn't find a way.
